# Javascript: assign value on arrays data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, node.js, express

Here is my code

```
function gotData(data){
        result = data.val() 
        const urls_kws = Object.keys(result)
                    .filter(key => result[key].last_res > 10)

        var keywords = urls_kws;

        console.log(urls_kws)

        for(var i=0;i<keywords.length;i++) {
        keywords[i] = keywords[i].replace(/-/gi, " " )
    }

}
```

Result is

```
[ '7-skinfood-gold-caviar-collagen-cream',
  'beauty-credit']
```

But when i move *console.log(urls_kws)* to below

```
function gotData(data){
        result = data.val() 
        const urls_kws = Object.keys(result)
                    .filter(key => result[key].last_res > 10)

        var keywords = urls_kws;

        for(var i=0;i<keywords.length;i++) {
        keywords[i] = keywords[i].replace(/-/gi, " " )
    }

        console.log(urls_kws)
}
```

Result is

```
[ '7 skinfood gold caviar collagen cream',
  'beauty credit']
```

My question is how can i keep value on `urls_kws` because i need to use both of var urls_kws(with -) and keywords(without -)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
    var keywords = url_knows
```

with:

```
    var keywords = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < url_knows.length; i++){
        keywords.push(url_knows[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`urls_kws` value is not getting changed. You are console logging outside the function. So it is showing different value.

You can check console logging in the last line of function, it would have remain same.

If you want to access the same `urls_kws` value even outside that function, make the variable global.

To make it global variable :

```
window.variableName= variableName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Lists are objects in JavaScript and objects behave differently. When you do this `var keywords = urls_kws;` you are actually creating another pointer for the object in memory.

To copy an object you can use this notation: `var objClone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object));`

```
function gotData(data){
    result = data.val() 
    const urls_kws = Object.keys(result)
                .filter(key => result[key].last_res > 10)

    var keywords =  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(urls_kws));

    for(var i=0;i<keywords.length;i++) {
        keywords[i] = keywords[i].replace(/-/gi, " " );
    }

    console.log(urls_kws);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

create new array instead of replacing values in original. 
e.g.

```
[ '7-skinfood-gold-caviar-collagen-cream','beauty-credit']
    .map(original => {
        return [ original, original.replace(/-/gi, " " )];
    });
```